# Entity Framework Core setting ID to get value from sequence

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, sequence

I have an existing postgreSQL database.
I've set up an Entity in my asp.net core project and I can mange to read it.
But when I try and write to the database I get an exception ID can't be null.
Error: **23502: null value in column**

Now I've tried overriding the OnModelCreating function with the values:

```
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("seq_name")
                    .StartsAt(1)
                    .IncrementsBy(1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                .Property(o => o.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"seq_name\"')");
```

But this does not work.
(Taken from [npgsql.org](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html#identity-and-serial-columns-auto-increment))
I tried all other OnModelCreating option but still same error.

In a java project I just added on top of the property:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mySeqGen", sequenceName = "seq_name", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "mySeqGen")
```

and that worked for it.

Any ides?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**
My Entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{

   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Int64 Id { get; set; }

   public int? UserId { get; set; }

   public char Status { get; set; }

   public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }

   public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

}
```

My Context:

```
public class RequestsContext : DbContext

{

    public DbSet<MyEntity> Requests { get; set; }

    public RequestsContext(DbContextOptions<RequestsContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public RequestsContext() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("my_id_seq")
                    .StartsAt(100)
                    .IncrementsBy(1);

        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                    .Property(o => o.Id)
                    .HasDefaultValueSql("nextval('\"my_id_seq\"')");

    }
}
```

My Saving function:

aps.net Code:

```
MyEntity myTmp = _mapper.Map<MyEntity>(myNewDto);
bool wasSaved = _myService.CreateSave(myTmp);
```

_myService.CreateSave code:

```
_context.Requests.Add(myNewEntity);
return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
```

**Update 2:** 
Why is my SQL generated statement trying to return the 'id' and not set it with a value from the Sequence?

```
STATEMENT: INSERT INTO requests (created_on, status, updated_on, user_id)

VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)

RETURNING id
```

Comment: what do you mean by `does not work`? you should be more specific about it.

Comment: Hi @AriBer,Can you share your entities and insert statements?

Comment: @Yinqiu updated my entities and saving functions

Comment: @KingKing meaning I still get the 'Error: **23502: null value in column**'

Comment: Has the default constraint (`HasDefaultValueSql`) been passed through to the database, by migrations, or otherwise (whatever you use to keep EF config and the database schema in sync)?

Comment: @gert-arnold I don't want it connected to EF for changes only to read my data...

Comment: What do you mean? What I ask is: does the *database* have this default constraint? It's the database that throws this exception.